# mongodb query to get field only in .NET code

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, extjs4, mongodb-.net-driver

Can anyone help to get the correct .NET (C# or VB.NET) of the following query:

```
> db.usercollection.find( {}, { username:1, _id: 0 } )
   { "username" : "testuser1" }
   { "username" : "testuser2" }
   { "username" : "testuser3" }
```

Basically I only want to return certain fields of the document. Also is there anyway mongodb c# driver will convert the result into a json format that can populate a grid (extjs grid) or chart, without me doing the conversion explicitly.

```
 Using mongo.RequestStart(db)
        Dim collection = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("usercollection").FindAll()
        Dim collection3 = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("usercollection").
                        Find({}, {"username:1", "_id:0"})
```

The collection3 line is not correct.

Tried the following too:

```
        For Each ruleSet In collection
            Dim rules As String = ruleSet.GetValue(0).AsString
            response = rules & response
        Next
```

But this gives error:

```
UNABLE TO CAST OBJECT OF TYPE 'MONGODB.BSON.BSONOBJECTID TO TYPE MONGODB.BSON.BSONSTRING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the results to specific fields you need to use `SetFields` on the `MongoCursor` like so:

```
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>.FindAll(); // or any other query
cursor.SetFields("username");
```

`MongoD` uses `BSON` which means `Binary JSON`. If you want to use it as a `JSON` use the extension method:

```
BsonDocument document;
document.ToJson();
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Just one more additional question: how do I limit only the username and not include _id (objectId)...d=[{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d2f2b3c60804b25bc5d2ca"), "username" : "testuser1" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("52d2f2f9c60804b25bc5d2cb"), "username" : "testuser2" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("52d2f2f9c60804b25bc5d2cc"), "username" : "testuser3" }]

Comment: @vbNewbie you mean you want to query only the username field without even the _id of that document?

Comment: yes sir. Is that possible? I need to map this data to a grid and would like to ignore the _id.

Comment: I think it's better to do that in the client. I'm not sure it can be done in the db. here: `cursor.Select(document => document["username"])`

Comment: you mean separate what data I need from the result set?

Comment: @vbNewbie pretty much, yes. Query only the username field, and if that comes with the id field, use only the username property.

Comment: @vbNewbie sure.. any time